# Wix / WixSharp installer. Track user cancel installation event

Tags: wix, wixsharp

I'm developing the installer using WixSharp. I want to track (catch, subscribe etc) the event when user clicks the cancel button (cancel / abort installation).

I want to track during the stage user inputs the data and during the installation files process as well. It's better no changing the standard UI dialogs but using custom action or something. But if changing UI is the only way it's OK.

[image]

The project UI type is WixUI_InstallDir.

Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can't track this button click if you use this project type. But you can customize this project type if you adds this dialogs forms in your project

[WixSharp Managed Setup - Cusom UI](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/tree/346f3479e19815368732fe070467a8c2933258d6/Source/Templates/ProjectTemplates/WixSharp%20Managed%20Setup%20-%20Cusom%20UI)

Just add dialogs from this project and cancel handler (i think you know how to do it in winforms). Don't forget to check **Project.cs**, there are dialogs sequence and ManagedUI parameter set.